# How to use JadeGateway to communicate between jade platform and external application

Tags: jsp, agents-jade

I want to send the submitted form data by a user on a jsp page to a jade agent so he can process that data. How can i achieve that?

Answer (score 3):

After doing more research i have found a solution on [this tutorial](http://technokayiti.blogspot.com/2008/01/how-to-use-jadegateway-to-bridge.html):
first, you have to create a servlet to which the jsp form submits, that servlet will initialize the jadegateway and send an ACLMessage to the agent containing the data submitted.
then, you have to create a cyclic behaviour who is waiting for the message and add it to the agent who will receive the data.